# (Almost) Robert Bringhurst Style Chapter Titles in Standard Book Class

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I have tried:

```
\usepackage[tracking = true]{microtype}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang] 
{\normalfont\huge\color{darkgray}}{\filleft\thechapter}{1em}{\filright\textls[120]{\normalfont\smaller}}
```

Not unexpectedly, I was wrong. (And I am still missing the ruler) What is the proper way? (I just want chapter name (smaller than chapter number) on the left and chapter number on the right.) (In title, I said (almost) because in the original style the chapter number is below the ruler. I am not trying to be *that* fancy.

PS: Having read the documentation (with my rather limited knowledge), I still do not fully understand how titlesec template works. When it comes TeX I am not nothing, but at least I thought I could follow simple templates. Could someone direct me to a source for an explanation for a dummy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps something like this is closer to your intent?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage[tracking = true]{microtype}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter} 
  {\normalfont\color{darkgray}\huge}
  {}
  {0em}
  {%
    \parbox[b]{.8\textwidth}{\raggedright\textls[120]{{\normalfont\smaller#1}}}%
    \parbox[b]{.2\textwidth}{\hfill\thechapter}%
  }
  [\titlerule]
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless} 
  {\normalfont\color{darkgray}}
  {}
  {0em}
  {%
    \parbox[b]{.8\textwidth}{\raggedright\textls[120]{{\normalfont\smaller#1}}}%
  }
  [\titlerule]

\begin{document}

\chapter{A TEST CHAPTER TITLE}
Some test text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How do you customize the vertical space between the title and the rule below? Playing with `\titlespacing*{\chapter}{xxx}{xxx}{xxx}` only affected the vertical spacing between the title and the text below (as well as the left horizontal spacing).

Comment: @blackened Include the space just before `\titlerule`, as in   `[\vskip10pt\titlerule]`, replacing `10pt` for the desired value.